# Updating Audiences in the Optimizely using the SDK

Tags: java, spring-boot, optimizely, featuretoggle

There is a requirement for updating audiences, we searched a lot, and apparently, there is no such feature in the java SDK.

The requirement is that there is a micro-service that notifies us to include a new audience in an already existing feature flag (we want to roll out a feature in our backends by cities) and we need to add the new audience programmatically to the audiences whenever the other micro-service tell us. This is not an A/B test or an experiment it is actually a rollout plan.
How should we achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. What exactly is an audience?

Comment: What you tried so far

Comment: @Pavel https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/target-audiences